# Angular 6 and RxJs 6 display modal if 401

Tags: angular, rxjs6

When I send a request and the response is a 401 status, I want to display modal box (with user and password) to relog the user and after, resend the original request.

I found really interesting post with the previous version of RxJs and I cannot update it to the new version [How to catch an error on a Request, then open a modal, then retry when modal closes with RxJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36654920/how-to-catch-an-error-on-a-request-then-open-a-modal-then-retry-when-modal-clo)

When I have a 401, my code display the modal, but in the same time, it resend my request and it doesn't wait the closing action.

Can you help me ?

```js
return this.http.get<Object>('http://localhost/test', httpOptions).
        pipe(
            tap(),
            retryWhen(errors =>
                errors.pipe(
                    tap(val => {
                        if (val.status === 401) {
                            let closedSubject = new Subject();
                            let modalRef = this.modalService.open(ModalLoginComponent);
                            modalRef.result.then((data) => {
                                console.log('closed me');
                                closedSubject.next(val);

                            }, (reason) => {
                            });
                            return <any>closedSubject;
                        }
                        else {
                            return Observable.throw(val.json());
                        }
                    })
                )
            )
        );
```

Comment: you want to use `catchError` operator instead of `retryWhen`

Comment: With catchError I cannot retry the request after the modal close action.

Answer (score 0):

I try this with AngularJs and I found a solution, but I cannot reproduce it in Angular 2+
Have you a solution to rewrite it in new Angular version ?

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(function ($injector, $q) {
    var modalInstance;
    return {
        'response': function (response) {
            return response;
        },
        'responseError': function (response) {
            var rootUrl = 'http://localhost/';
            // If this not login request and 401
            if(response.config.url != rootUrl+'login/' && response.status == 401) {
                var deferred = $q.defer();
                var $http = $injector.get('$http');
                var $uibModal = $injector.get('$uibModal');
                // Open login modal
                modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
                    templateUrl: rootUrl+'public/js/views/modalLogin.html',
                    controller: 'DialogCtrl',
                    keyboard: false,
                    backdrop: 'static'
                });

                // Modal result
                modalInstance.result.then(function () {
                    $injector.get("$http")(response.config).then(function(resp) {
                        deferred.resolve(resp);
                    },function(resp) {
                        deferred.reject();
                    });
                });
                return deferred.promise;
            }
            return $q.reject(response);
        }
    };
});
```